# Creating a screensaver with PyGTK for xscreensaver

Tags: python, pygtk, screensaver

I want to create a screensaver (for xsreensaver) written in Python and PyGTK. But I have the problem that I cannot handle the window id got by command line.

The following call is a sub process of xsreensaver (when I have open the xscreensaver preferences), I think that the given window-id is the ID of the widget in which the screensaver have to put the "preview" screensaver:

```
/usr/lib/xscreensaver/spampy -root -window-id 0x1E00CBC
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can put something in it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`gtk.Plug`](http://pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkplug.html), which is a GTK container that embeds itself in a window if you give it a window ID.

Comment: Can you write a small example? Because a modified version of plug.py from http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-PlugsAndSockets.html is not working (the screen is blank).